# Build a string with a JSON object in powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I write val1 in the below string? This should be really straight forward surely, but I can't find an example anywhere

```
$jsobj = @"
    {
    val1 : "test",
    val2 : "test1"
    }
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json


Write-Host @"
    Value of val1: $jsobj.val1
"@
```

Comment: Use `$($jsobj.val1)`

Comment: Cheers - I was trying things like that but with curly braces - if you put this as an answer I'm happy to mark it as that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to prevent early expansion of your variable to access its property value. The sub-expression operator `$()` allows everything inside to be evaluated as an expression.

```
$jsobj = @"
    {
    val1 : "test",
    val2 : "test1"
    }
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json


Write-Host @"
    Value of val1: $($jsobj.val1)
"@
```

When a variable is inside an expandable string (one with outer double quotes), the variable is substituted with its `ToString()` value. Anything after that variable is treated as part of the string rather than the variable. See below for a trivial example.

```
$str = 'my string'
"$str.Length"
my string.Length
```